# PL/SQL loop with while

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop

the problem is, the loop is not counting as need:

I need to count for example: a DVD price at 100% is equal with 64$
at 95% is 60.8$
at 90 it must take the original price (64$) and make 90% from this amount, but instead, he is counting from the last (60.8$) price and he is doing 90%.

```
create or replace procedure PR_PRICE
is V_PRICE DVD.AMOUNT_PRICE_DVD%type;
p_counter number(3):=100;
begin
    select AMOUNT_PRICE_DVD into V_PRICE
    from DVD
    where TITLE_DVD like '%pop';
 --   p_counter :=100;

    while p_counter >= 80 loop
        V_PRICE := p_counter*V_PRICE/ 100;

        dbms_output.put_line('The price of DVD at ' || p_counter ||'% is: ' ||  V_PRICE ||'$');
        p_counter := p_counter-5;
    end loop;


end PR_PRICE;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding `v_price`, create a different variable for the discounted price:

```
create or replace procedure PR_PRICE
is 
V_PRICE DVD.AMOUNT_PRICE_DVD%type;
V_DISCOUNT_PRICE DVD.AMOUNT_PRICE_DVD%type; -- Declared here
p_counter number(3):=100;
begin
    select AMOUNT_PRICE_DVD into V_PRICE
    from DVD
    where TITLE_DVD like '%pop';

    p_counter :=100;

    while p_counter >= 80 loop
        V_DISCOUNT_PRICE := p_counter*V_PRICE/ 100; -- Calculated here

        dbms_output.put_line('The price of DVD at ' || p_counter ||'% is: ' ||  V_DISCOUNT_PRICE ||'$');
        p_counter := p_counter-5;
    end loop;


end PR_PRICE;
```

Comment: @don'tknownothing If the answer is what you were looking for... don't forget to mark it as such.  Otherwise this still pops up as unanswered and leaves the question 'open' for lack of a better word.  It also helps the individual(s) who are taking out their time to answer your question(s).